# Changing x-axis input range with each iteration of plot

Tags: matlab, for-loop, 3d, mesh

I am trying to plot 5 subplots in a for loop, each iteration of which varies with x (1 to 5). However, I would also like to change the range of R for each iteration so that it is equal to 6*x:100 - so when x=1, R=6:100; when x=2, R=12:100; when x=3, R=18:100; and so on... 
I've been trying to figure out how to do this for days, so help would be much appreciated.

```
% constants
de = 20;
b = 0.5;

% parameters
x = 1:1:5;
R = 6.*x:100;
S = 0:1:250;

[R,S]=meshgrid(R,S);

% function

k1=@(x)((factorial(R)).*exp(b.*(x.*(de))));
k2=@(x)((S.^(6.*x)).*(factorial(R-6.*x)));
kk=@(x)(k1(x)./(k1(x)+k2(x)));


figure
for i=x
    subplot(3,2,i)
    mesh(R,S,kk(i))
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified a bit your code,without anonymous functions and inserting everything within the for loop, I hope its the answer you are looking for. for a clear visualization I linked your rotation axis, so youll allways look to the same angle in each of the 5 subplots.

```
% constants
de = 20;
b = 0.5;

% parameters
S = 0:1:250;    

figure
for x=1:5
    R = 6.*x:100;
    [Rk,Sk]=meshgrid(R,S);

    k1=((factorial(Rk)).*exp(b.*(x.*(de))));
    k2=((Sk.^(6.*x)).*(factorial(Rk-6.*x)));
    kk=(k1./(k1+k2));
    h(x)=subplot(3,2,x)
    mesh(Rk,Sk,kk)
end
linkprop(h, 'CameraPosition');
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic - thank you ever so much; just what I needed!